# Read responses in Perl

Tags: perl

In my code below, how do I get the result from the su command ?  @output only contains the result of myCmd, but not of the su command.  Thanks!

```
 $cmd = "su test -c 'myCmd'";
 $pid = open2(*README,*WRITEME, $cmd);
 $pw='abc';
 print WRITEME "$pw\n";
 @output = <README>;
 waitpid($pid, 0);
 my $child_exit_status = $?;
 close(WRITEME);
 close (README);
 foreach $lf (@output) {
   print $lf;
 print $child_exit_status;
```

Comment: What output from `su` are you expecting to see? The password prompt is likely done via direct console I/O.

Comment: I want to see the error when I put in a wrong password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error output is going to `stderr`.  Use `IPC::open3` to capture it.

Per @ikegami's comment: Using open3 to read both STDOUT and STDERR is extremely complex. Continue using open2 but adding 2>&1, or use IPC::Run

Comment: No. Using `open3` to read both STDOUT and STDERR is *extremely* complex. Continue using `open2` but adding `2>&1`, or use IPC::Run

Comment: @ikegami Fair enough. I've made the answer CW, feel free to update.

Comment: Thanks very much Jim Garrison and ikegami!